# Wrong status bar height while editing moreViewControllers

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9, uitabbaritem, ios8.1

I have an iOS app with a "More..." button at the UITabBarController. 
When I am hitting "More..." the new view appears that has an "Edit" button
on top right. Clicking "Edit" shows the view in Edit mode, see at the attached image.

The problem with the edit mode is that the "Done" button is shown below the correct position (see the green arrow) or to put differently the bar takes more space than it should be? Why that happens?

"Done" should be on the top right position and the bar should have less height. I guess that I need to change things in

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController willBeginCustomizingViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers
{

}
```

but I don't know what exactly happens here.

Code at *iOS8*.

[image]

Comment: This image is not that helpful unfortunately. Could you perhaps indicate on your image exactly what you would like to change?

Comment: What are your auto layout constraints, i would guess, they are not correctly configured...

Comment: Would it be possible for you to upload a minimal working demo which contains this bug on Github or somewhere? That would help a lot in trying to solve your bug.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a navigationbar with prompt. Maybe the presented viewcontroller inferred this property in your storyboard/XIB-File.

Answer (score 0):

More tab is default behaviour of Tabbar controller, but your the image shows something is modified. Refer image. **If you are implementing default method of UINavigationController in category**. Do remove it and build again. [image]

Comment: If you are implementing default method of UINavigationController in category. What do you mean?